# Submatrix rank question

Tags: linear-algebra

If an $m\times n$ matrix with $m>n$ has full rank, does that imply that that uppermost $n\times n$ submatrix is invertible (also has full rank)?

If not, is it true at least that some combination of $n$ rows can be taken from the matrix to form an invertible matrix? How would one go about doing so?

Comment: BTW, the study of which subsets of vectors are independent are precisely what led to the development to matroid theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to note is that an $m \times n$ matrix with $n>m$ cannot have rank $n$, since otherwise we would have $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Having full rank (in this case rank $m$) implies that there is some $m \times m$ invertible submatrix, but this is not necessarily the uppermost submatrix.

Comment: How would you go about finding that submatrix though?

Comment: You can use Gaussian elimination to put the matrix in row echelon form, and pick your rows so you get an invertible matrix.

Comment: Finding the submatrix depends on the values. You're going to have to be a bit more general than that.